# how to fix a missing logo in internet explorer

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer

In this site : [renovationm.com](http://www.renovationm.com/) I have a logo at the top and in any browser except explorer 9 (as said by customer) its fine, in explorer it's gone!. what cause it to disappear and how to fix it.. or troubleshoot it ?

i think about including a library like http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ but i dont think for that specific problem it will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the extra / in the path after http:// is the issue in IE:

```
<img src="http:///renovationM.com/jobs/logo.png"> <!-- Notice the extra / -->
                 ^
```

Comment: I can think of a browser sooooooo touchy !... thanks a LOT men, my mistake.